# Does Hybris use Spring Framework?

Tags: spring, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to understand and get some information for the Hybris platform. Does it use Spring Framework? Also could anyone please share the link / material to have more understanding about it's architecture, technology, etc ?

As per my research, they use:

**Technology:**
Spring MVC, JSF (FrontEnd), REST Web services ?????

**User Interfaces:**
Product Cockpit, CMS Cockpit, Print Cockpit, Admin Cockpit, HMC

**Platform:**
Persistance, Caching, Security, Internationalization, Import/Export, Search

**App Server:**
Hybris Server, Oracle BEA, IBM, JBoss

**Database:**
Oracle, SqlServer, Mysql

**IMP:** Does `SAP Hybris` support for `Spring REST`. I think since it uses `Spring MVC + Security`, so **restful web services** should of `Spring REST` only. I heard that it also support `RestEasy and Jersey`, but not good option when you have a `Spring REST` in place which adds great support than `RestEasy and Jersey`. Can you bring in details ?

Can someone please answer to the above IMP query ? Also please share sample RestFul web service of SAP Hybris.

Comment: Hi, yes hybris uses Spring. hybris is a proprietary framework, you can find info on their website but you won't find a lot of technical stuff if you don't have a partner account.

Comment: Is this open source or paid service ?

Comment: Its not open source. Partner companies have to pay a fees for its license.

Comment: What is the official link of hybrid with all documents included?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hybris uses the following technologies:

Java, Spring, Apache SOLR, Groovy, Scala, Apache Commons, ZK framework, Google Analytics, Jasper Reports, Tomcat.

You can find the best information on the architecture of hybris [here](https://help.hybris.com/6.2.0/hcd/8b5588d8866910149d4eb5f99c75b6b4.html).
You need a SAP Hybris login for this.

Comment: What is the future of Hybris in near future? How it is good for 5+ years Spring MVC + Restful services Developer?

Comment: Hybris is growing fast in e-commerce solution due to B2C and B2B capabilities. It has more advantage then using legacy platform like ATG. So if you become Hybris developer , the future is bright because e-commerce as whole growing at faster pace then normal retailing business and currently top three e-commerce platform solution in market.

Comment: If you like programming and worked on Spring then you will love programming in Hybris and it will be easy if you understand Hybris Models.

Answer (score 4):

Spring core, Spring MVC.

JSP, javascript, CSS, bootstrap for the frontend.

java 8 for the backend.

apache Solr as the search engine.

tomcat, spring tc server, oracle, IBM as server.

hsqldb, oracle, IBM SAP HANA, MySql, Percona etc as database.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

hybris does use spring and many other frameworks (like zk, groovy, scala). They have there own persistence layer and they does use the MVC pattern a lot. As hybris provide a lot of different services and interfaces it is not clearly only one architecture.

e.g. the "datahub" is a communication gateway based on spring integration, but Independent from the base platform.

Comment: Can you give idea what all technologies are there in Hybris platform ?

Answer (score 0):

Hybris use spring mvc spring security. it is compatible with Mysql, HANA, Oracle, sqlserver etc. Also it comes with charon api which make it easy to interact with yaas platform specially designed to fulfill the requirement of other ecommerce feature. you can access it through following link : click [here]:help.hybris.com
But again it is not free. You can also try on http://www.slideshare.net/

Comment: Does this uses Spring Restful services? Ideally naturally spring rest is best option, but I heard it support RESTEasy and Jersey. Is that true? Can you update your ans to support it ?

Comment: spring restful service is used.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. I would be expecting more detailed answer. Could you please guide?

Comment: Its not bounded you to use spring restful you can also go for resteasy and jersey. Only you will have to include libraries.